# Is there a GUI program to copy files selected in a tree view?

Tags: windows, file-management, gui

I'm looking for a graphical tool that would allow me to copy a folder structure from one place to another, selecting and deselecting individual files and folders for copying, including selecting parts of the content of previously deselected folders.

The representation I have in mind for a tool is a tree view where each node has a tristate checkbox:

```
☑ File 1
☐ File 2
☑ Folder 1
  ☑ File 1.1
  ☑ File 1.2
☒ Folder 2
  ☐ File 2.1
  ☑ File 2.2
```

Here, the destination would contain this hierarchy after copying:

```
- File 1
- Folder 1
  - File 1.1
  - File 1.2
- Folder 2
  - File 2.2
```

Windows Explorer only allows me to copy whole folders over. Copying tools like TeraCopy allow deselecting individual files, but show all selected files in a list, making it impossible to get an overview.

Comment: I found [this page](http://www.javaquizplayer.com/examples/copy-files-app-using-javafx8-example-source-code.html), but not knowing what to do with this. I just cannot believe there are so few people that find such a utility essential: first you freely select what you want (or don't) to copy and when you're done,just launch the process and do something else.